# Modal Overlay Causes Problems with other Links on Same Page

Tags: java, modal-dialog, selenium-webdriver

My main web page contains several links and one of them is a modal. 
When I click on "Learn More" (see HTML code below) a modal opens on top of the main page. I'm able to compare the expected and actual links but for the remaining links on the main page, I'm unable to compare the actual and expected. These links display their content in a separate window. The HTML has no IFRAME tags.

Thank you,

```
 <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ExpirationDate" class="ExpirationDateSkin">
 <span class='topCopy'>Enter your account # below and<br />click "Register" <br /> to take advantage of this promotion.
 </span><div class='learnMoreLink'>
 <span class='adaScnReaderText'>open overlay 
 </span>
 <a href='#'>Learn More</a></div></span>
```

Here is the code you requested. Please read question above.
Thanks,

```
 String mainWindowHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolder1_ExpirationDate']/div/a")).click();

 Set s = driver.getWindowHandles();
 Iterator i = s.iterator();
   while(i.hasNext())
 {
String popupHandle=i.next().toString();
if(!popupHandle.contains(mainWindowHandle)) {

driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
 }

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='enroll']/div/div/a")).click(); 
 }
```

Comment: How about sharing some of your code (whatever is relevant for this question)?

Comment: Please see the code you requested. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to a different location, in many different ways.

A few examples:

- `driver.get(...)`
- `driver.switchTo().frame(...)`
- `driver.switchTo().window(...)`
- `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`
- `driver.findElement(...).click()`
- `driver.navigate().back()`
- `driver.navigate().forward()`
- `driver.navigate().to(...)`
- `driver.navigate().refresh()`

But once you do that, any element that you have acquired from the previous DOM may become "stale".

In order to avoid this in your specific example, first save a list of all the relevant window-handle strings:

```
List<String> handles = new ArrayList<String>();
Set s = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator i = s.iterator();
while (i.hasNext())
{
    String popupHandle = i.next().toString();
    if (!popupHandle.contains(mainWindowHandle))
        handles.add(popupHandle);
}
```

Then, switch to each window and do whatever you wanna do on that window:

```
for (String handle : handles)
{
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    // Do whatever you wanna in here
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Please note that on some web pages, the window-handle names may change as you go "in and out" of the web-page. This case can also be dealt with, but it's a little trickier; let me know if help is required...